# Keras: Interpretation of model.predict() for image classification

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras, multiclass-classification

I have created an image classifier using keras and I am trying to use `model.predict()` for a single image. My code looks like this:

```
path = 's.jpg'

from keras.preprocessing import image

img_width, img_height = 224,224

img = image.load_img(path, target_size = (img_width, img_height))

img = image.img_to_array(img)

img = np.expand_dims(img, axis = 0)

a =model.predict(img)
```

But the output array 'a' with probability scores is always in descending order.  Do you have any idea why?? I have three categories.

Comment: They are not in descending order, it is just by chance that it happened with this specific image

Answer (score 0):

The predict returns class probability, `[class1_prob, class2_prob, ....]` assuming you have `softmax` in your model.

It should not be always decreasing unless you pass such data so that for which the class probability is always in decreasing order.

Comment: I realized that I didn't scale the image array i.e.                                                                                           img = image.img_to_array(img)/255 and hence it gave rubbish output.